# Add Custom Legend with Color Indicator ASP.NET Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-visualization

Straightforwardly.. May i ask how to create a custom legend at the bottom of my charts?

Legend would be.. **Red** Low Bed Number

Codes in designer:

```
                <asp:Chart ID="ChartClass" Visible="false" runat="server" Height="500px" Width="720px"> 
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="SeriesAvailableClass" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelAngle="-90" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt" Legend="LegendClass" ChartArea="ChartAreaClass" ChartType="Column">
                        <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="false" />
                    </asp:Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="SeriesAllotedClass" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelAngle="-90" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt" Legend="LegendClass" ChartArea="ChartAreaClass" ChartType="Column">
                        <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="false"/>
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartAreaClass">
                        <AxisX Title="Class">
                            <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
                        </AxisX>
                        <AxisY Title="Number of Beds">
                            <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
                        </AxisY>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
                <Legends>
                    <asp:Legend Docking="Bottom" Name="LegendClass"></asp:Legend>
                </Legends>
                <Titles>
                    <asp:Title Name="TitleChart" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 15pt, style=Bold" Text="Beds Statistics Summary (Class)" Alignment="TopCenter"></asp:Title>
                </Titles>
                </asp:Chart>
```

Codes back end:

```
        Series seriesAvail = ChartClass.Series.Add("SeriesAvailableClass");
        seriesAvail.Color = Color.ForestGreen;
        seriesAvail.LegendText = "Available Number of Beds";
        seriesAvail.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        seriesAvail.LabelAngle = 0;
        seriesAvail.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8);
        seriesAvail.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;


        String[] classArrAvail = { "A1", "B1", "B2", "C1" };
        int[] countAvailable = { A1Available, B1Available, B2Available, C1Available };

        ChartClass.Series["SeriesAvailableClass"].Points.DataBindXY(classArrAvail, countAvailable);

        foreach (DataPoint pt in ChartClass.Series["SeriesAvailableClass"].Points)
        {
            if (pt.YValues[0] < 10)
            {
                pt.Color = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (pt.YValues[0] >= 10)
            {
                pt.Color = Color.ForestGreen;
            }

        }


        Series seriesAlloted = ChartClass.Series.Add("SeriesAllotedClass");
        seriesAlloted.Color = Color.SkyBlue;
        seriesAlloted.LegendText = "Alloted Number of Beds";
        seriesAlloted.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        seriesAlloted.LabelAngle = 0;
        seriesAlloted.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8);
        seriesAlloted.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;

        String[] classArrAlloted = { "A1", "B1", "B2", "C1" };
        int[] countAlloted = { A1Alloted, B1Alloted, B2Alloted, C1Alloted };

        ChartClass.Series["SeriesAllotedClass"].Points.DataBindXY(classArrAlloted, countAlloted);
```

Image:

[image]

I have tried looking and searching online. Can't seem to find any reliable sources or solutions that i'm looking for.

Most of the solutions are having legend added to a specific series.

I'm fairly new to ms-chart...

Appreciate any help. Thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following code after you build your series:

```
    LegendItem item1 = new LegendItem();
    item1.ImageStyle = LegendImageStyle.Rectangle;
    item1.Color = Color.Red;
    item1.BorderColor = Color.Red;
    item1.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.SeriesSymbol, "", ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
    item1.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Text, "Low Bed Number", ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft);
    ChartClass.Legends[0].CustomItems.Add(item1);
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much jstreet! have yet to try it, but i'm sure it works! sorry was busy with other stuff in my project.. thank you a lot!

Comment: No rush, take your time.